# Difference between --rerun-tasks and --refresh-dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I would like know what is the difference between both, --rerun-tasks refresh all dependencies or it uses it locally?

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html Is there any reason you couldn't find it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing [application dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html) between [task dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks).

Per the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:rerun_tasks):

> This will force `test` and all **task dependencies** of `test` to execute.

So `--rerun-tasks` has nothing to do with dependencies you define for your application.

Comment: ok, in that case, whem I use --rerun-task I am not refreshing the dependencies, right?